# Direct image of structure sheaf under a dominant map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth complex projective varieties with $dimension(X)>dimension(Y)$. Suppose that we have a rational map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ defined on an open subset of $X$ which is a complement of finitely many points. Let $X'$ be the blow up of $X$ at those points. Consider the morphism $f':X'\rightarrow Y$.

What is the direct image $f'_*O_{X'}$? Is it $O_Y$? How do we see that?

Comment: Look up Stein factorization. In general, the rank of $f'_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}$ at a point is the number of connected components of the fiber over that point, so there's no reason for it to be 1 everywhere as it would need to be if $f'_*\mathcal{O}_{X'}\cong\mathcal{O}_Y$.

Comment: Thank you @KReiser. Will the direct image be a trivial bundle?

Comment: As per my last comment, there is no reason for that to be the case in your setup.

Comment: @KReiser, I am considering now the toy example where $X=P^n$ and $Y=P^m$ and $n>m$ and $f$ is projection from a point. So $f$ is defined on the complement of a point. In this case the fibres of $f$ are affine. And fibres of $f'$ are connected right?